# m3u parsing with batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, m3u

I would like to parse Artist and title of song from m3u playlist with batch command

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:151,TJR - We Wanna Party Into We Want Some Pussy (BB Tribe EDIT)
\#Mixit\pjesme\TJR - We Wanna Party Into We Want Some Pussy (BeatBreaker Tribe EDIT).mp3
#EXTINF:202,Alan Walker - Alone (Prisoners Bootleg)
\Users\Asrock 880\Downloads\Alan Walker - Alone (Prisoners Bootleg).mp3
#EXTINF:236,Alan Walker - Alone 2k17 (#Ash Simons Bangerz) (Ft. Holl & Rush)
```

so the output .txt file will look like this

```
TJR - We Wanna Party Into We Want Some Pussy (BB Tribe EDIT)
Alan Walker - Alone (Prisoners Bootleg)
Alan Walker - Alone 2k17 (#Ash Simons Bangerz) (Ft. Holl & Rush)
```

Any help will be useful, thanks

It can be power shell too or anything other but with a better description I'm DJ... :P

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: simple one-liner. See `for /?`. You need proper tokens (`2`) and delimiters (`,`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- So you want only the information on the lines beginning with
  `#EXTINF` following the comma.
- you will find hundreds of examples on [SO] working with `findstr` to select lines with a pattern (see [findstr /?](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html))
- and also with `for /f` to parse the content of a line with delimiters and tokens (see [for /?](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html))

---

In a batch:

```
@Echo off
(For %%M in (*.m3u
  ) Do For /f "tokens=1* delims=," "%%A" in (
    'findstr "^#EXTINF" %%M'
  ) Do Echo %%B
) > Playlists.txt
```

On the cmd line:

```
@For /f "tokens=1* delims=," %A in ('findstr "^#EXTINF" playlist.m3u') Do @Echo %B
```

To redirect to a file enclose the for command in parentheses and append `>playlist.txt`

Comment: any way to add more playlist at the same time?

Comment: This is really basic batch stuff :-( You should put more effort in **your** task.  A simple `for`  loop can iterate with a wildcard. I'll extend the batch sample above for now but extending a question is a nogo in  [SO]. Notice the down votes and the close requests on your question. Take the [Tour] and learn [Ask]

Comment: I'm not kinda into that and I am so sorry... also thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone wanted to remove the PowerShell tag, so here is a one liner:

```
(Select-String *.m3u -Pattern '^#EXTINF') -Replace '^[^,]+,'|Out-File PlayList.txt
```

Comment: I like the way you said "Someone wanted to remove the PowerShell tag" :)